# Server Sent Event and asp classic

Tags: html, asp-classic, server-sent-events

I made a ASP script with all headers necessary for Server Sent Events. 
The client side script is working. I tested it with a PHP script and it works fine.
The ASP script works and it returns the expected message if you call it from the URL line, but when the javascript calls it, the element inspector returns the data as "undefined". 
When I set the breakpoint to the "open" event listener, the "e.data" is "undefined".

For some reason Javascript is not accepting the UTF-8 text sent by the ASP script.

Help me please!!!

The asp code:

```
strResponse = strResponse &  "data: " & now() 
response.Buffer = true
response.CharSet = "utf-8"
response.ContentType="text/event-stream"    
response.AddHeader  "content-Type", "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8"
response.AddHeader  "Cache-Control", "no-cache"      
response.AddHeader  "Content-Length", len(strResponse)
response.AddHeader  "Connection", "Keep-Alive"
response.Write strResponse
```

The Javascript:

```
if (!!window.EventSource) {
    var source = new EventSource('serversend.asp');
    source.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        console.log(e.data);
    }, false);

    source.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
        console.log("open " + e.data);
    }, false);

    source.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
        if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            console.log(e.data);
        }
    }, false);



} else {
    // something else :(
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It might help if you posted some code.  Also,if your asp script works then it sounds as if this is a javascript problem rather than an asp one.

Comment: Hi @John , thank you for taking the time to help me. The ASP code is bellow. I know the javascript code is working becouse it works with my PHP script.
`code`
strResponse = strResponse &  "data: " & now() 
response.Buffer = true
response.CharSet = "utf-8"
response.ContentType="text/event-stream"    
response.AddHeader  "content-Type", "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8"
response.AddHeader  "Cache-Control", "no-cache"      
response.AddHeader  "Content-Length", len(strResponse)
response.AddHeader  "Connection", "Keep-Alive"
response.Write strResponse

Comment: unless there's something earlier in your code which populates `strResponse` it won't contain anything other than "data:" and the current time - is that all you want it to contain?

Comment: What happens if you use the full external path in your js - ie `var source = new EventSource('http://yourdomain.com/serversend.asp');`

Comment: @John, nothing happens with the full URL. Same "undefined" response. The element inspector can't read the response. I made a regular ajax call and it returned the expected text. 
The problem is how ASP Classic handles stream :(
Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `Response.Flush` after `Response.Write`

Edit* 
Put two enters after the strResponse string:
`response.Write strResponse & vbCrLf & vbCrLf`

Comment: Could you please explain why and reference the appropriate documentation

Comment: The reference is w3schools: www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp.

Comment: But that's not the erros, i have discovered: you need to put 2 enters after string...
`response.Write strResponse & vbCrLf & vbCrLf`

Answer (score 3):

Try This Is Working

```
Response.Write("data: The server time is: " & now()) & chr(13) & chr(10) & chr(13) & chr(10)
```

Response.Flush()