# Receive Server-Sent Event Notifications

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have this example of server sent events from w3schools. The .php code works fine. However, I need the .asp version and that example doesn't work. I not getting any response from the server side script. Any help?

```
     <!-----------Client side-------------->

     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>

      <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
      <div id="result"></div>

      <script>
      if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
      var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.asp");
      source.onmessage = function(event) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
      };
      } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
     }
     </script>

     </body>
     </html>

     <!---------------Server side--------------->

     <%
     Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream"
     Response.Expires = -1
     Response.Write("data: The server time is: " & now())
     Response.Flush()
     %>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server Sent Event and asp classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339704/server-sent-event-and-asp-classic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not believe this but... try this line:

```vb
Response.Write("data: The server time is: " & now()) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

This works for me! [See this answer - the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339704/server-sent-event-and-asp-classic)

Comment: Ok, how odd is that? That actually works! Thank you Ralpharamma, you are both a scholar and a gentleman. Now if I can just manipulate it for my needs. I'll be set.  Thanks again and have a great day!

Comment: Let me ask you another question while I have your attention. I there a way to have it replace what it has already written and replace that with a new value. I'm thinking of using on a '<span>numValue</span>'. I'm trying to use the code to send notifications to the user in real time if that help explain a bit.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. I'm at least slightly more evolved then Homer Simpson... lol