# Server sent events (SSE) not working in Classic Asp on IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic, server-sent-events

I wonder if anyone have faced the same issue: Server sent eventd (SSE) are not working in Classic Asp on IIS (version 10) as they used to. It seems that the issue has appeared with modern browsers because in one of my older IDEs with older browsers (ie, crome) integrated as part of still shows SSE. Strangely enough, I don't get any errors in server side or in the browser's console, and the 3 different test browsers (Edge, Chrome and Firefox) act the same: nothing gets rendered on browser's screen irrespective of the successful response from the server (http status 200). In browser's network tab I cannot figure out anything why text/stream content from the backend is not rendering (on screen and not in console via console.log). What is also strangely enough is that sending from IIS-backend indeed takes place because in network tab periodically new responses (from SSE.asp) gets listed with status 200 code but with no streamed data involved and data getting rendered or logged in console:

[image: Browser network tab]

*Below are my most simple demo codes.*

**SSE.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

    if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        var source = new EventSource("SSE.asp");
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
               console.log(event.data)
                   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
        };
        } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Getting server updates</h1>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**SSE.asp**

```
<%
Response.Charset = "utf-8"

Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream"
Response.Expires = -1
       
Response.Write("data: The server time is: " & now())
%>
```

I have tried many things to overcome the issue:

- disable browser cache
- disable firewall in PC
- caching disabled serverside
- tried even in remote IIS server (shared hosting environment)

Nothing of these did not help.

Can anyone figure out what is the cause and solution for this issue?

Comment: could you try disabling compression in iis.

Comment: Did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a solution which actually was already here in the databases of stackoverflow, but which the system did not suggested to me as the potential already found solution while I was writing this question/post (so, there is something to be refined and tweaked in the system which creates suggestions for solutions). Anyway here is the direct link to the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49536412/7625979.

The solution was simple basically: SSE response body requires that there is a 2 new line symbols added to the end of response in order to be able to separate difference responses (sendings) from one another.

Therefore this solves the issue:

Response.Write("data: The server time is: " & now()) & chr(13) & chr(10) & chr(13) & chr(10)

See this for sending format documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#event_stream_format